# What is the difference between “within” and “inside”?

Tags: difference, vocabulary, connotations, word-meaning

Here is the definition of the word *within* from Oxford Dictionary:

> inside (something)

So does that mean the two words have no difference, and can be used exchangingly? Is there any connotation that one word can be used but not the other?

Comment: I of course meant _you do not have a choice of either, you can only use within_

Comment: You [can use *inside* with time](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/inside).

Comment: @Andrew - True, but you'd use it differently, I believe: _Finished within an hour_ vs _Finished inside **of** an hour_.

Comment: No, *inside* is never used with *of* in BrE. (Or at least, it's not standard)

Comment: On a slightly tangential note, do not use Google Translate, *especially* not for single words. It needs context. A lot of context. More than any dictionary will ask for. Simply do not use it for single words. You will only get into trouble. It will translate "Friday morning" as "Thursday morning" and you won't even notice. Do not do it. Why don't people use dictionaries anymore?

Comment: @ЯegDwight I am at the office, and I didn't bring a dictionary. Yep, bad grammar too in google translate

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between "within" and "inside"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/10099/difference-between-within-and-inside)

Comment: @Andrew: Interesting! That's how I'd say it over on this side of the Atlantic. Evidently, it's [not just me](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/inside-of#inside-of_1).

Comment: @Aldi: You **always** have a dictionary available. Start here: http://onelook.com.

Comment: @ЯegDwight very good point. I know someone who tried to translate the English adjective "kind" (meaning "having good behavior") into Spanish using an automated translator and came up with "tipo", which is the Spanish equivalent to the English *noun* "kind" (itself synonymous with its cognate noun "Type").

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Inside** may be used while describing **position/location** as opposed to outside.
Example: The box is blue colored inside and black outside.

Within may be used for **time/space**.
Example: I'll reach there within ten minutes.  Stay within the boundaries.

Comment: Will this answer be improved inside the hour? :-)

Comment: The answer, though highly upvoted, is problematic. Is a "location" clearly different from a "space"? No. One can quickly appreciate the problem here by searching online for "positioned within", for example.

Answer (score 14):

Like any two synonyms, there will be contexts where you can use **either one**, and there will be other contexts where most people would **choose one word over the other**. These two words are such general-purpose words (with some [**idiomatic usages**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/earshot?showCookiePolicy=true) as well) that I don't think we can begin to cover all the bases (that would not be **[within reason](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/reason_2)**).

That said, here is one example where either word works just fine:

> There were many troubles hidden *inside* Pandora's box.
>   There were many troubles hidden *within* Pandora's box.

Here's one place where I'd clearly use *inside*:

> After the rain started, we [went **inside** the house](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=went%20inside%20the%20house,went%20within%20the%20house&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).

and another where I'd clearly use *within*:

> Would Freddy be traded to another team? That was **[within](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=within%20the%20realm%20of%20possibility,inside%20the%20realm%20of%20possiblity&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)** the realm of possibility.

You can always use the [Ngrams tool](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inside%20the%20tunnel,within%20the%20tunnel&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) to check if a certain usage can [go both ways](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inside+the+tunnel%2Cwithin+the+tunnel&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), or if it [generally doesn't](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inside+the+scope%2Cwithin+the+scope+&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=). The Ngrams tool is not infallible, but, if you have an internet connection, it's always **[within reach](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/within+reach)**.

<sub>There are a lot of external links embedded **within** this answer; I hope they lead to some fruitful research for the O.P.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Their meanings are similar, but they are likely to be used in different contexts. *Within* is perhaps a little more formal and dated. There is an important grammatical difference you need to be aware of. *Within* can be used only as a preposition and an adverb. *Inside* can additionally be used as a noun and an adjective.

Comment: Could you give me a sample sentence for `within` and one for `inside` ?

Comment: @Aldi - You should be able to find your own. Here are links to thousands of samples from published books: using [_within_](https://www.google.com/#q=%22It+was+within+the%22&safe=off&tbm=bks), and using [_inside_](https://www.google.com/#q=%22It+was+inside+the%22&safe=off&tbm=bks).

Comment: Do you want to show me the books??

Comment: The blue words are links. Click on them; you should be able to see sentences (unless there is some sort of restriction at your connection).

Answer (score 0):

They more or less mean the same thing.

*Inside* is more literal, one thing is in the other thing, like in a box.

*Within* doesn't necessarily mean "inside". You buy a VCR, and there's the user manual included within. That doesn't mean you need to unscrew the cover or take it out of the battery container of the VCR. It means it's in the box, included with the VCR. You buy a computer magazine and there's a CD included within - but the CD is in an envelope glued to the front cover, not inside the magazine. Of course "within" may as well be "inside" - you buy a toy, and "3 AA batteries included within" - they may be in the box, and you need to load them into the toy, or they may be already loaded and inside the toy. Anyway, "Within" is the middle ground between "Inside" and "Bundled" (the latter meaning included in the set, but definitely outside of the core item)

Comment: I'm not sure if I buy your explanation. The manual isn't included *within the VCR*, it's included *within the packaging*. It could equally be described as *inside the packaging*.