# Difference between "within" and "inside"

Tags: difference, prepositions

I am Indonesian and I think my English is bad especially when it comes to vocabulary. One day I ran into the words *within* and *inside*. I opened Google Translate, translated both words into Indonesian, and the meaning was the same. It said "dalam". So what is the difference between the two?